# select2 dropdown remains open when using browser 'back' button

Tags: meteor, jquery-select2, meteor-blaze

step 1) on my Form page, I open a select2 dropdown

step 2) without clicking anywhere else on the Form page, I select the browser's 'back' button

result: prev page is loaded but the select2 dropdown persists.

NB: select2 closes successfully when user goes anywhere else in the app/screen itself (using the menu) - it is only when using the 'external' controls of the browser that the select2 remains open.

I'm using Meteor, jQuery and handlebars

Things I've tried:

```
  Template.teamsForm.onDestroyed(function () {
    if ($('select').data('select2')) {
      $('select').select2('close');
    }
  });
```

[image of step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csJxC.png)
[image of step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgIJE.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the solution was to update the Jquery library to 3.4.0  After I did that the dropdown select was operating as if you never left the page.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but it works

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
    $(".select2-container").removeClass("select2-container--open");
});
```